# list download files in umbraco 4.11.8

Tags: umbraco

Hi we have created a doc type with a tile, description and an mediaPicker uploadcontrol

Using this we have uploaded a small number of test files. We now want to list the files by title and description (done) and prvide a link which when clicked, directs the browser to upload the file from the node listed. All example we can find are for earlier versions < 4.5
and cant get them to work in 4,11.8....

the line we are having problems with is:

```html
<a href="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/uploadFile, 'false')/umbracoFile"/>
```

or

```html
<a href="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/uploadFile, 0)/umbracoFile"/>
```

which give a "too big" int32 error

What are we missing please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
<xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/uploadFile, 0)" />

<xsl:if test="$media">
        <xsl:variable name="url" select="$media/umbracoFile" />
        <xsl:variable name="width" select="$media/umbracoWidth" />
        <xsl:variable name="height" select="$media/umbracoHeight" />
        <img src="{$url}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" />
</xsl:if>
```

You can find more info on the wiki of Umbraco: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/getmedia

Comment: couple of days off, thanks, but I'll try when I get back on Monday and score approriately thanks